# Understanding the clout score issue

Tags: twitter, social-networking, klout

in my twitter profile which is kushalshah02 there are more than 50000 tweets and 15k followers and i am also following more than 15k people.

I have integrated this profile with my klout then also my klout score is 38.

Contradicting this my friend twitter account - frogmode having less then even 1000 followers and less then 2500 tweets though he has integrated his that profile in klout and his score is 62.

I have also asked he has not integrated any other profile to his klout.
Then how it can be possible?

am i breaking klout protocols? is this the reason that why i am not having so much good score ?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, but this might help: http://xkcd.com/1057/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking to explain how Klout works, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things that go into a Klout score. Just having a lot of followers will not increase it. They filter out known spam accounts and then look at things like retweets on twitter. Your friend likely gets more people to reply/retweet his content. You get a larger bonus for tweets that get spread by more than just *your* followers. Finally, the more social networks that you connect to Klout the higher your score can go. They are looking for "true reach," so your reach theoretically grows with more networks.